# Android: Google Maps API v2 how to clean up child SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I have a SupportMapFragment added programmatically with `getChildFragmentManager()` in my `onCreate()` method.

When I reopen the app after the activity has been closed, the app seems to be rendering the old child `SupportMapFragment` without the markers. The old child fragment isn't interactable either.

How do I fix this lifecycle issue with `SupportMapFragment`? Do I need to call a specific detach method or something to that effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was to do with the way I was handling my child fragments.

Every time the parent fragment would call `onCreate` the children fragments would get recreated.

I did the following to handle my child fragments, but there may be a better way:

```
private static final String TAG_FRAGMENT_MAP = "TagFragmentMap";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // create the fragments for the first time
        ft.add(R.id.view_flip, new SupportMapFragment(), TAG_FRAGMENT_MAP);
        ft.commit();
    }
}

// ...

public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)findFragmentByTag(TAG_FRAGMENT_MAP);
}
```